# Cordova - change index page if in debug for qunit js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cordova

Does anyone know how to create a hook to copy a new index.html to a project after prepare is run so that I could replace the apps normal startup page to be a qunit js testing page?

I had a look at http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/ and what she does with stage and prod to change api access and others is really cool!! but I have 0 idea how to tell cordova via cli that it needs to run stage prod or my new qunit setup. she doesn't include her commands to get it running like that.

Also, if anybody knows any other good getting started with hooks in cordova articles or tutorials that would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://intown.biz/2014/05/13/build-configurations-in-cordova-using-hooks/ is a bit more explanatory... But I think it is suggesting that i set TARGET environmental value which is a bit of a bummer for me...

If anyone has a good solution please drop an answer or a comment.. When I get a chance I am going to see how possible it is to create a file like buildType.js which will just contanin some key value pair data for environment setup, then i'll create  a js script for node that accepts a param, set the param to the config settings i want (it will then pull those config from those settings and

Comment: put them into another file, this new file the hook will use to do it's thing when it's changing the index over.. Not allot of experience in writing stuff in node so don't know how successful ill be, ill check in later